# How can I cluster articles with 2 embeddings (english and french)?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, word-embedding, fasttext

I have a dataset of articles containing french and english content. My final goal is to have similar articles that are in same cluster.

What I did first is word embeddings with fasttext. So I have word embeddings for french and another one for english content.

How can I do next to make a only one clustering with these 2 embeddings ? Is there a good practice ?

Comment: Did you think about using multilingual aligned fastText model (https://github.com/babylonhealth/fastText_multilingual) ?

Comment: Thank you I'm going to check it

Comment: Let us know if this solves your problem...

Comment: Hello, yes thank you @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87